# R ggplot date time issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to get a simple xy plot to work where the date time is on the x-axis.  I have tried amalgamations of several posts on this to no avail.

Here is the sample data:

```
datetime,temp,humidity
2017-10-15 15:00:00,84.05,36.36
2017-10-15 16:00:00,84.21,36.21
2017-10-15 17:00:00,82.74,41.79
```

I imported the csv as "env"

I then run this code:

```
env$'date-time' <- as.POSIXct(env$'date-time',format = "%y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
library(scales)
x <-ggplot(env, aes(x='date-time')) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = temp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = humidity)) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
x
```

This is the error:
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

```
str(env) produces this:
 $ date-time: POSIXct, format: "2017-10-15 15:00:00" "2017-10-15 16:00:00" 
"2017-10-15 17:00:00" ...
 $ temp     : num  84 84.2 82.7 83.1 83.2 ...
 $ humidity : num  36.4 36.2 41.8 45.2 46 ...
```

Comment: Your example data has `datetime`, your code has `date-time` (with a hyphen). Which is correct?

Comment: Yes.  Simple typo as I was playing with the column name.  Removing the "-" obviates the need to quote the name.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
env$'date-time' <- as.POSIXct(env$'date-time',format = "%y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Format should be `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: This will work if the column is named `date-time` (as it is in the question code), as opposed to `datetime` (as it is in the question example data).

Comment: @neilfws Yes, but assuming the column is named correctly, the `format` specified in the first line of provided code is wrong

Comment: I know. I was just highlighting the ambiguity in the variable names.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, code updated as follows:             
names(env)[names(env) == 'date-time'] <- 'datetime'
env$datetime <- as.POSIXct(env$datetime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Error: Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only.  All the prior code was updated to use 'datetime' vs date-time.